# Vi editing for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, vim, ide, editor

I'm used to the Vi(m) editor and am using MS Visual Studio 2005 at work. I couldn't find a free Vi add-in (there's only one for the 2003 version). I googled a bit, saw that there was a 'Google summer of code' project this year to write such an add-in, and am eagerly awaiting the result. I've also heard of ViEmu (not free, and I can't test it at work).

Has anyone in my situation has found a solution (and/or tested ViEmu)?

Edit: I can't test ViEmu at work because they are paranoid about what we install on our boxes: it has to go through required channels, and for 30 days I don't reckon it's worth it (and I have no Windows box at home).

Edit: Since both answers were equivalent, I ended up accepting the first one that came in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ViEmu works great with Visual Studio.  I used Vi(m) strictly in Linux, but I was turned on to bringing the Vi(m) editing process into the Windows world by [JP Boodhoo](http://www.jpboodhoo.com/).  JP [praises](http://blog.jpboodhoo.com/HookedOnVIM.aspx) about it also.

Answer (score 3):

[ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com/) works great. I've been using it for about a year now and couldn't imagine coding in Visual Studio without it.

Why can't you test it at work? It has a 30 day free trial.